# How can I store HTML in a DB (SQLITE PYTHON)

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite

This is probably quite simple, but I can't get there...

How can I store html code in a SQLITE Data Base?

I'm using text as the data-type for the field in the DB (should it be blob??)

I'm getting weird errors (and changing erros with the same input, so I think it has something to do with escaping)

MY CODE:

```
con = sqlite.connect(bd)
cur = con.cursor()
temp=cur.execute ('SELECT * from posts').fetchall()
#temp[Z][1] = ID
#temp[Z][4] = URL
i=0
while i< len (temp):
    if temp[i][0]==None:
        try:
            html = urllib2.urlopen(str(temp[i][4])).read()
        except:
            html=None
        #sql = 'UPDATE posts SET html = "' + str(html) + '" WHERE  id = ' +  str(temp[i][1])
        #cur.execute( 'UPDATE posts SET html = ? WHERE  id = ?' ,(html,temp[i][1]) )
        cur.execute("UPDATE posts SET html = '" + str(html) + "' WHERE  id = " +  str(temp[i][1]))
        con.commit()
        print temp[i][4]
    i=i+1
```

The errors:

1 -

> OperationalError: near "2": syntax
>   error WARNING: Failure executing file:
>    Python 2.6.5
>   (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
>   Type "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.

2-

> ProgrammingError: You must not use
>   8-bit bytestrings unless you use a
>   text_factory that can interpret 8-bit
>   bytestrings (like text_factory = str).
>   It is highly recommended that you
>   instead just switch your application
>   to Unicode strings.

P.s. I would rather If it would be text (human readble) than blob, but if it's the easier way, I'm all for it.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
cur.execute(
    "UPDATE posts SET html = ? WHERE id = ?", (html ,temp[i][1]))
```

Use parameterized arguments to allow sqlite3 to escape the quotes for you. (It also helps prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).)

Regarding the ProgrammingError: `html` should be a unicode object, rather than a `string` object. When you open the url:

```
response=urllib2.urlopen(str(temp[i][4]))
```

Look at the content type header:

```
content_type=response.headers.getheader('Content-Type')
print(content_type)
```

It might say something like

```
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
```

in which case you should decode the `html` string with the `utf-8` codec:

```
html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

This will make `html` a unicode object, and (hopefully) address the `ProgrammingError`.